# How can I add SVN support to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I have AnkhSVN installed & working with VS2008, and TortiseSVN is installed & working fine for desktop integration.

I just downloaded & installed a trial version of VS2010 , and would like to be able to use svn, but the only option is to bind to a TFS server.

How can I add svn support to VS2010?

Comment: AnkhSVN supports VS2010 as well but I believe you should re-install after the VS2010 setup.

Comment: I tried that, and followed the directions to go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection, but the only option is TFS.

Comment: That's strange. Which version did you install? I would try to de-install all AnkhSVN version first (you said you already had it running with VS2008) and re-install only the latest version.

Comment: I tried that.  I suspect that because it's a trial version, it's partially crippled to only work against TFS.

Comment: That could be true, but I would doubt it. Another way could be to first install VS2010 SP1 before installing AnkhSVN and the have clean reboots, after de-installation and re-installation of AnkhSVN. In my opinion it should really work even with the trial.

Comment: What version of AnkhSVN did you install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the trial version is crippled to only allow connection to TFS.

Here are the steps I tried - if anyone has different results, I'll be happy to update this.

- install VS2010 Trial
- install AnkhSVN 2.1.10129
- result:  No SVN plugin available

I then uninstalled both VS2010 and AnkhSVN.  I borrowed a licenced VS2010 Professional CD, and followed the same steps, and was able to select the SVN plugin.

Comment: I think it's the trial that's to blame then